# Reply To Triggered Send

Tags: marketing-cloud, email, c#, send-email, triggered-send

I am trying to send a Triggered Send email through ExactTarget and have the recipient reply to that email directly to my company Exchange server.
i.e. Call ExactTarget API to send the email and when the recipient replies it goes to me@mycompany.com instead of ExactTarget.

My salesforce knowledge is quite poor and it seems that there is a lot to know, so I may be going about this all wrong...

I can send emails through ExactTarget without any problems, but I can't figure out how to configure the 'reply to' so that it comes directly to my desired email address. I think I need to use Send Classifications, but I don't know how and am struggling to find good documentation on it.

Here is the code of my attempts so far:

```
public string SendTriggerMail(string emailAddress,
                            string subscriberKey,
                            string triggerMailId)
{
    IExactTargetService exactTargetServiceClient = new ExactTargetServiceClient
            {
                ClientCredentials = { UserName = { UserName = "", Password = "" } }
            };

    var id = new ClientID { ID = 1234567, IDSpecified = true };
    var definition = new TriggeredSendDefinition
    {
        CustomerKey = triggerMailId,
        Client = id,
        FromAddress = "test@test.com",
        FromName = "Test",
        SendClassification = new SendClassification
        {
            SenderProfile = new SenderProfile
                        {
                            ReplyManagementRuleSet = new ReplyMailManagementConfiguration
                            {
                                EmailReplyAddress = "test@test.com",
                                EmailDisplayName = "Test",
                            }
                        }
        }
    };

    var send = new TriggeredSend { TriggeredSendDefinition = definition, Client = id };

    var subscriber = new Subscriber
    {
        EmailAddress = emailAddress,
        SubscriberKey = subscriberKey
    };

    var allAttributes = new List<Attribute>
                {
                    new Attribute { Name = "SomeAttribute", Value = "AttributeValue" }
                };

    subscriber.Attributes = allAttributes.ToArray();

    send.Subscribers = new[] { subscriber };
    APIObject[] sends = { send };

    var response = exactTargetServiceClient.Create(
        new CreateRequest(new CreateOptions(), sends));

    return response.OverallStatus;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you might need RMM (Reply Mail Management):

http://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/exacttarget/admin/reply_mail_management/

Answer (score 0):

It's much easier to create the Triggered Send Definition in the actual account interface instead of trying to do it with the API.

You can define the Sender Profile in the Administration tab, then set it in your Triggered Send Definition.

Then your API call can just [**execute a TriggeredSend**](http://help.marketingcloud.com/en/technical_library/web_service_guide/technical_articles/send_triggeredsend_email/) by Customer/External key.

These might be helpful:

- [**SenderProfile answers**](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/search?q=%5Bmarketing-cloud%5D%20sender%20profile%20is%3Aanswer)
- [**Modify the From Address in a TriggeredSendDefinition**](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/140992/trigger-emails-not-able-to-modify-the-fromaddress-using-triggeredsenddefinitio/141007#141007)
- [**Workflow for using a Trigger**](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/85512/5202)

Comment: Thanks! The reason that I am doing the way I do is that I have no access to the Exact Target web interface, that is all controlled by a marketing department. As software developers we are stuck with the API. I will have to see if I can get access to the web front end and see what I can do from there.

Comment: `sudo grant full SFMC access to @GlenThomas`